# In Locke & Key, how does Dodge levitate?

Tags: locke-and-key

Dodge levitates in the Locke & Key comics, but at the point when he does this he doesn't have any keys (yet).

Is this an ability he has because he is an echo? Or because he's possessed by a demon?

[image]